# Override screensaver?

Tags: air, screensaver

This is a long shot but...we have an Air app that needs to run continously, even if the computer has a screensaver. Is there any way to detect and override that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want a way, without user intervention, to force your application to run continuously, overriding the users choice in the matter?

Programs that do that are usually called viruses.

How 'bout a big dialog box that says "Turn off your screensaver".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Thanks for your response!